# Admin Panel and User Profile logged in in the same time

Tags: php, session, authentication

First of all I will explain what is the issue about:

*When I log in in user's profile I am able to access the `/adminboard/index.php` , the admin panel itself and vice verse- when I log in into `adminboard` I access the profile of the first user registered.* This makes my site unsafe of cause.

I think the reason is the code of session I have made. The `adminboard` and the user profile have identical log in codes. Probably I have to change variables' names to prevent this bug, but I do not know exactly which one.

```
    //code in `PHP` of log in forms:
    ob_start();
session_start();
include '../includes/config.php';
$password = $_POST['txtPassword'];
$username=$_POST['txtUserName'];


$query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username= '$username';";
 mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // User not found. So, redirect to login_form again.
{
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo '<script> alert("მონაცემები არ მოიძებნა რადგანარ ხართ დარეგისტრირებული. დარეგისტრირდით პრეტესტზე") </script>';
echo '<script language="JavaScript"> window.location.href ="../register.php" </script>';
}

$userData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );

if($hash != $userData['password']) // Incorrect password. So, redirect to login_form again.
{
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo '<script> alert("პაროლი არასწორია! '.$password.' , '.$userData['password'].'") </script>';
echo '<script language="JavaScript"> window.location.href ="../login.php" </script>';

}else{// Redirect to home page after successful login. 
    session_regenerate_id(); 
    $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $userData['id'];
    session_write_close();
    header("Location: ../adminboard/");}
```

the same is for users but the "location" address is different.

```
//and here is the user session checker for index.php-s in adminboard and 
//Start session
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) || (trim($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) == '')) {
header("location: ../login.php");
exit();
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code that populates `$userData`

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is super insecure. My username is `'; DROP TABLE admin --` etc etc. Consider using [PDO](http://php.net) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) and binding your parameters.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ but i thought hash was ok. Do you mean it cant stand against injections?

Comment: You're not hashing the username (why would you?). You're not validating any input that is being passed into your queries, or sanitizing, or using parameter binding. In short, your application is very insecure.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the session name using `session_name('myDummyName')`. Use different names for your front and back-end. Both will use different sessions afterwards. Make sure to set the session name before calling `session_start()`